Why do betting markets disagree with polling - US Election 2024
As things stand, betting markets have an implied probability of Trump winning the 2024 election of around 60%.
Conversely, most polling has Harris ahead by 3-5%.
Why is there such a huge disagreement?

Are you aware that in the USA, the president is not selected by a direct national popular vote?

@Obie2.0 - Yes, but if you project the polls over the swing states likely to decide the election, if I'm not mistaken, Harris still has a slight lead

Many of these bets seem to be from outside of the US AFAICT https://www.bnnbloomberg.ca/investing/2024/10/22/polymarket-cracks-down-on-us-based-users-as-whale-bets-on-trump/

According to 538, Trump has actually been very slightly ahead for the last few days. It’s really the proverbial “too close to call”.

Also relevant perhaps to look at 2020 https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2020/12/trump-betting-markets-sportsbooks-offshore-2020-election-gambling.html

Relevant podcast, which asks this very question: https://freakonomics.com/podcast/how-to-predict-the-presidency/

Eve of election betting odds: https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2024/nov/04/presidential-election-betting-odds-polling

The polling is much tighter than the question suggests. The FiveThirtyEight model, which at this point in the election cycle is dominated by polling, has Trump's odds of winning at 51%.
Harris leads in the national polling averages by 1.7 percentage points which is significantly less than what she needs to win.
In light of the distortions of the Electoral College relative to the popular vote, and the fact that a "contingent election" in which the Electoral College is tied and states vote one-state, one-vote would almost certainly go to Trump, a Democrat needs something between a three to four percentage point lead in the national polling to win the Electoral College vote.
In the 2020 Presidential election, a 3.4 percentage point lead in the popular vote was what it would take a Democrat to win the Electoral College. This year isn't much different.
But, in any case, ultimately, national polling doesn't matter in the U.S. Presidential election system. There are only seven U.S. states that are remotely close in this election and they will decide the outcome. The polling averages in those states as of today are as follows:

As a practical matter, Pennsylvania is extremely likely to be the marginal state that decides the election outcome and it currently leans in favor of Trump in recent polling by 0.2 percentage points. Moreover, the trend line in Pennsylvania polling and in other swing states in the last two or three weeks have been trending in Trump's favor.
How do you get from 60% to 51%? People's evaluations of trend lines. They aren't trying to predict how people would vote today, they are trying to predict how people will vote over the next twelve days.
And, keep in mind that the difference between a 51% chance of winning and a 60% chance of winning is much less than one standard deviation of variation in percentage point leads in polling results. Realistically, this is a difference of less than one percentage point in the average polling results. It is still very close to a toss up prediction.
Also, there is the fact that not everyone in a prediction market is betting sincerely. Some participants bet as if their preferred candidate is more likely to win than that candidate really is, in hopes of creating an impressing of positive momentum and inevitability, knowing that it means that the participant might lose money. The stakes aren't high enough for wealthy participants to care too much about making a factually accurate prediction. Making an absurdly optimistic bet in favor of your favorite candidate winning is  not really any different than making a campaign contribution.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution FiveThirtyEight estimates that the odds of Harris winning the popular vote and losing the Electoral College is about 19%, so about 2 out of 5 times that Trump wins, he doesn't win the popular vote. And, indeed, it has happened multiple times in recent history and always benefitted Republican Presidential candidates.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution People betting in prediction markets may be taking into account the fact that polling in both 2016 and 2020 had a strong anti-Trump bias.

"How do you get from 60% to 51%? People's evaluations of trend lines. They aren't trying to predict how people would vote today" -- I believe 538 isn't "trying to predict how people would vote today" either. It says it seeks to "account for potential movement in the race between now and Election Day". ...

... Now, there can certainly be differences in judgment on how to most accurately estimate potential movement, but I wouldn't say that's necessarily the explanation for 51% versus 60%, which as you note is effectively well within the margin of error anyway. There can be various small effects where bettors deviate from 538 (different modeling frameworks, different evaluations of poll reliability, market trading noise, etc.). The main conclusion is that both 538 and markets are reasonable estimates.

OK, but you have systems like The Economist and 538 that have 53% Trump/47% Harris odds as of last week.  Those are not polls, they are statistical analyses built on top of polls.  The Electoral College is a known mechanism to them, so is the extra margin needed for the Dems to win.  If the betting markets are at 60% and other analyses (not polls) are calling it in the 48-52 likelihood (either way, because that has flipped), then the betting markets just work differently.

re: 51% to 60%. 1) Before everything, reading odds of a bet is different from reading futures pricing on interests. If the odds are provided by the bets maker, then the odds can be skewed by the predicted popularity of either bet, depending on how the payout is calculated. The odds only have to reflect weighted average of betters' bets when the total payout comprise of solely the bets from betters. While that can be true, that does not always maximize profit for bet makers or minimize liability for them. So without knowing how the bet payout is calculated, there is not necessarily explanations

to be made.  2) Insincere betting would require that participants in those betting markets are significantly skewed towards preferring Trump. That is actually a non-trivial claim, which is probably worth mentioning in the answer. However, while I am not aware of direct evidence, such a trend would still be plausible if for example other broad based sentiment measurements in the US also exhibit political bias. That turns out to be indeed the case as Jim Bianco tweets how UMich consumer sentiment index exhibits correlations to political

bias. (At the time of writing, said Twitter account happens to be posting arguments related to election betting markets -- on how they are not manipulated or, not necessarily insincere. One argument is that betting rates should predict polls.)

All in all, I think using insincere betting as explanation would be better labelled as one plausible explanation out of several.

You speak of insincere betting as a major skew in odds, I doubt that.  There is little to gain out of throwing money towards skewing a betting poll, and few who would think it worth doing.  I think the bigger effect is sincere but irrational voting.  IE I like this candidate there for I believe they will win regardless of the polling being near even.   It's not a rational vote for who is most likely to win but instead a vote for who they wish would win.

@dsollen It doesn't take a lot of money to skew the odds. Bill Gates dropped $50 million on ads for Harris. Many conservative billionaires have spent more to back Trump. At present, the overall economic scale of prediction markets is very modest. You only need one or two wealthy insincere betters to dramatically skew the results, and it takes only slightly more mischief to have that spending broken up among a large number of minions funded by the wealthy instigator.

FWTW, roughly the same betting markets were giving Trump 70% in 2020, during the election night.
Many of those who bet in these are not US citizens due to legal restrictions. (Although the restrictions are sometimes bypassed due to the on-line nature of some of these markets and judiciary flip-flops.)
How well informed those placing bets are, who (really) knows? Some past big bettors claimed to have some kind of insider information on campaign strategies etc.
Also, males are more likely to bet in these things, and males also favor Trump. (First source.) More generally, participants in these markets seem to consist of both people who at least claim to play just the probabilities (i.e. use some kind of model) and those who might play their political biases somewhat (more). Or at least when you interview someone, they claim to be in the former category, cleaning out the latter.
Also from the 1st source, in many of these political betting markets the odds are announced by a bookmaker and they are not motivated to set it at a market clearing (i.e. event outcome) level, even in their own estimation, but at a level that factors in the inherent biases of the bettors. Exactly the same thing happens with sports betting, which allows the bookmakers to make larger profits than a market clearing house would.

Also ohwilleke's answer is correct that these markets are small enough to be biased by 'whales', e.g.:

The odds on Polymarket began favoring him [Trump] this month after just four accounts, with user names like Fredi9999 and PrincessCaro, bet more than $30 million on a Trump victory, according to an analysis of transaction records by Chaos Labs, a crypto data provider. Polymarket said on Thursday that all four accounts were controlled by one person, whom it described as a French national with a financial services background, without revealing the person’s identity.
[...] Polymarket allows users to gamble an unlimited amount of money. [...]
For much of the fall, Polymarket’s odds suggested that Mr. Trump and Ms. Harris were locked in a tight race, mirroring the polls. Then the odds diverged substantially this month, after the four accounts placed large bets on the former president.

Also, it seems that Polymarket only accepts bets in cryptocurrencies, which already kinda limits who'd be interested in putting their money in that of vehicle in the first place. Another related point of bias is that Trump has apparently declared himself "pro-Bitcoin" or at least he is so touted in the cryptocurrencies media.
If I'm to put it this way, Musk has probably already bet much more on Trump (even if not in the form of formal bets), so IDK how relevant it is that some anon French guy bets some millions, which may or may no be his.

N.B. Thanks to ItalianPhisolopher's for mentioning this in a comment. One can indeed incorporate other info beside polling in prediction model. E.g. The Economist puts Trump at 53% chance to win (and Harris at 47%) as of right now but they include a variation on the Abramowitz model in their prediction, which (normally) includes "the president’s net approval rating, GDP growth, and whether or not a first-term incumbent is running for re-election". And from they also mention the overfitting, and how to avoid it etc. Their variation, by the way is at least to "assigned a penalty to parties that had already been in power for at least two terms" instead of the incumbent thing. And for state-level results they use as biasing prior which party won the past two elections.
This is just give some idea how a prediction model can use info other than polls. Whether it's the right/best model is not something I'm going to get into here. And it's also unknown what model most bettors use, I think.

Bookmakers set their odds with the ideal outcome for an event involving two opponents being that the bookmaker makes money regardless of which side wins. So if the betting community is predominately male, and males tend to prefer Trump, it makes sense to set the odds in Trump's favor.

Citing that bettors are not US citizens, as a primary issue that would distort election markets, seems odd. In general, markets are fundamentally different from polls, because markets ask who you think will be president whereas polls ask who you think should be president. The former has, in the end, a unique objective answer, whereas the latter is entirely down to individual opinions. Some bettors may get confused between the two, but they would tend to be small amateur players who approach it as entertainment; they will tend to lose money. ...

... Big money players cannot afford to confuse "will" and "should", and would make every effort to check their bias at the door and bet based on an informed prediction (not preference). Of course, there is a connection between polls and markets: Polls of US citizens (more precisely, of likely voters) are crucial data that inform a rational bettor. Foreign bettors would still use US polls (they would do the same type of analysis as anyone) -- the market outcome isn't like a poll of non-US citizens would be. ...

... In the end, as ohwilleke's answer explains, the (possibly foreign-dominated) betting markets are fully consistent with the US polls, once you account for the Electoral College, margins of error, and potential changes in public opinion through election day.

I skimmed through that article.  Thing is, while the betting systems are not in the US, the article specifically stated that a lot of US money flowed in, with the bulk of the punters being Trump backers.

@DavidHammen: Indeed, while I don't know about what bookmaking markets exist today, some of the markets were run by firms that were set up so that the entities administering them would have zero stake in the outcome.  At any time prior to the final election result being determined, one could buy or sell a bundle containing one share of "X will win", one of "Y will win" and one of "Someone other than X or Y will win", for a fixed price of exactly $1, and at all times all kinds of shares would exist in equal quantities, so the total market capitalization would be equal to the number of...

...bundles that existed in the market.  Once the final election result was determined, the shares of the winning answer would be worth $1, and all others worthless.  Since the number of $1 shares would equal the number of bundles sold, the amount that would need to pay out would be precisely equal to the amount invested, less fees.

@DavidHammen: It's the opposite. If bet makers set odds (as opposed to letting the total payout equal to total bets, minus fees), the more popular a bet is, the less odds is required to attract bets. Bet makers are motivated to offer as low odds as possible for either bet. Such odds are not directly useful to give probability. PolyMarket probably isn't like that though.

@nanoman: Polls used for modelling election outcomes are usually who you are going to vote for. NOT who you think should be president. Your demographic info is a part of the answer too. There is also an objective answer to that.

"Polymarket only accepts bets in cryptocurrencies, which limits who'd be interested" <-- they do have relatively higher odds atm, but their historical trend does not deviate from the other betting sites. As well, if the market is small enough, and/or unlinked from other financial markets enough, 5%-10% difference would be insignificant and does not carry the usual meaning of 5%-10% ppl may expect in, say, the futures market on interest rates. So that could be worth pointing out in the answer. Otherwise, great pull of sources.

@Argyll OK, I should have said who of the two realistic candidates you think should be president. The vast majority vote based on that question (because they want to vote in a way that increases as much as possible the probability of the outcome they prefer). Only a small number vote pointlessly for a non-viable candidate whom they would theoretically prefer but who has essentially zero chance of winning.

Betting markets are not polls. Polls say what the situation is now. Punters try to predict the future.
Punters will take information from polls and voting models and combine it with their intuition about what will happen in the future to arrive at a "wisdom of crowds" judgement about the election.
There's no magic here. Punters don't know the future, so they can collectively be wrong.  People form judgements based on "feelings" as much as "facts".  Here, people may be looking back to 2016, and compensating.  Back then, many punters had discounted Trump (he was too weird, too extreme, too tainted to be President) and lost money on the result.  Here punters might have that in their mind, and compensate by backing Trump more strongly than the poll evidence alone would suggest.
However, there aren't big differences. Your numbers aren't quite right. The latest 538 averages has a Harris lead of 1.7%. Both the polls and the betting sites say the election is close to a toss-up.

538 says that she leads in the popular vote, but the final EC result is actually extremely tight, very very slightly favouring Trump.

Minor note: 538's main driver/brain was Nate Silver who has quit the company and now runs his own modeling on his blog, which is widely considered to be more accurate than 538's model in 2024.

@JonathanReez: he's also consulting for one of the bookmaker companies in Q here. But that's not to say that company publishes polls. What they publish are odds that will maximize their profits given the run-of-the-mill bettors' biases.

There are several factors in play here.
Statistics
Even assuming everything - both in polling and the prediction market - was perfectly executed and that the election were a straight popular vote competition. We would still see a huge difference between the polled percentage of voters for each candidate, versus the percentage chance of winning. Why? Because of statistics. In the limiting case, as K. A. Buhr points out, a perfectly accurate poll would be equivalent to the election itself; if you count every voter and know who they'll vote for, then the "probability" of winning is necessarily 100% for one candidate and 0% for the other.
More realistically, a poll has a margin of error. The probability of winning, in this scenario (we'll also assume for simplicity that we know exactly who is going to vote, and we know that nobody will change their minds between the poll and marking the ballot) is the probability that the actual share of Candidate A voters is on the same side of 50% as the polled result. We can't actually directly calculate that, in fact, but if we assume some baseline probability distribution (for example, we might guess that the share of voter each way is probably somewhere close to 50-50; it's possible to be quite far away, but less likely the further away), we can use the poll as information that changes our assumption. The assumption is called a prior and, being rational and precise, we determine the shift using Bayesian statistics.
The EC system
To get a sense of those priors, we can look to historical results. As it happens, the US system is not at all a straight popular vote competition - but we can nevertheless build a model that historically compares the popular vote to number of Electoral College votes, and a model for the typical error in polling, and a model for the typical variation from 50% in popular vote numbers. And if we put all those things together, we can build a model that translates, in a very rough way, the polled popular vote percentage to a probability of winning.
And if we do this, two facts will stand out very strongly:

Because of how the Electoral College assigns additional votes per state, the party preferred by voters in rural areas (currently that's the Republicans, and it isn't close) will have an inherent advantage.

Probabilities in the 50% region are very unstable; a tiny change in polled popular vote can translate into a massive shift in that probability. In other words: the effect of a "perfectly accurate poll" is seen to a significant extent, because it turns out that even fairly simple polling is pretty good.


If we then try to refine the model, to take into account the fact that the EVs in most states are all-or-nothing, one more fact will jump out: only a few "swing" states' votes really matter in any race that's even a little bit close, because the votes in the other states are basically a done deal. A state-level poll in a state that breaks about 60-40 might not do a great job of figuring out whether it will break more or less than 60-40; but it will be extremely confident who wins there, and that winner takes all.
Polling inaccuracies
Polls can be off for any number of reasons. Pollsters generally try to correct for this (unless their poll only exists to make one candidate look good), but errors can still happen. Modelers also try to correct for this. 538's model is especially sophisticated. It doesn't just run simulations to account for the factors described above. It also considers the possibility of a systemic bias in polling (in extreme cases, one can even imagine a subset of the population deliberately trying to deceive pollsters); rates polls for accuracy and weights them when it tries to build a picture of each state's voters; and considers correlations between states (e.g. if something is causing polls to be inaccurate in Pennsylvania, there's a good chance the same factor also affects polls in Ohio, but less of a chance it affects polls in Florida). These factors have a lot to do with why 538 gave Trump a significant chance of winning in 2016 when many other commentators had written him off entirely. (In many cases, it's not clear they'd built any kind of model at all.)
Market inefficiencies
On the flip side, there are any number of reasons why a prediction market could fail to settle on a good probability estimate. Of course, voters can simply be irrational. As ohwilleke points out, there's good reason to guess that the subset of the population likely to be interested in using prediction markets skews towards Trump, and people could overvalue Trump "shares" based on overconfidence or simply thinking that the rest of the world thinks like them.
But even with market participants who "know" a fair probability estimate and behave rationally, this still isn't a guarantee. Why? Because there are rational reasons to "price" the shares differently, due to real-world concerns. In particular: typically, a prediction market doesn't offer any risk-free return.
As described in this comprehensive blog analysis, suppose at the point where "no" shares for RFK were trading at 97 cents (i.e. the share is a bet that RFK will not win, and the price implies a 97% probability of this happening), you decided this was an underestimate and that the true value should be 100 cents (i.e. it's impossible for him to win). Even if you're right, the price could be "correct". That's because you're "entitled" to make that 3 cent profit, on the grounds that:

This money isn't risk free; the prediction market could default, or be a scam.

There's opportunity cost involved; you could put that money in money-market funds and possibly make as much or more money "risk-free" (or as close as it gets).



I feel like most of the answers so far have missed the point.
You are comparing two percentages that are measuring different things.  The percentages in a poll try to measure the proportions of votes.  The percentages in a betting market reflect the proportions of participants who believe one or the other candidate will win.
There is no reason these percentages should be close. And -- despite the issues raised in other answers -- this has very little to do with the quality of the polls, possible biases and prejudices of participants in the betting market, the possiblity betting markets are trying to predict the future instead of the present, or the role of the electoral college in deciding the presidency.
If there was no electoral college, and we were all pre-programmed robots with 49% of us programmed to vote for Harris and 48% of us programmed to vote for Trump, then a high quality poll would show percentages of 49% versus 48%, but a completely rational betting market aware of our robotic status and our programming would assign a (nearly) 100% probability to a Harris victory.  Because, robots!
More realistically, if current polling showed Trump ahead 60% to 40%, betting markets would probably assign a probability of a Trump victory of close to 95% or more.  That's because, generally speaking, people cast their vote for who they want to win; they bet on who they think will win.  Not the same thing!
Update:  I'm assuming you were trying mostly to understand the size of the disagreement, given that you asked why it was so "huge".  The direction of the disagreement -- the idea that Harris is ahead (by whatever amount) in polls but Trump is ahead (by whatever amount) in the betting market -- is another matter and represents a genuine discrepancy. In this case, the issues raised in the other answers start to come into play.  It's generally irrational to accept that candidate A is ahead in the polls but candidate B will win EXCEPT if you think that the poll might not reflect the final vote (through a combination of margin of error, systematic bias, trends, etc.) or that the electoral college will propel candidate B to victory even if the popular vote matches the poll, etc.

I think the question also hinges on that betting markets favor one candidate and polls favor the other. Even though I agree with you that the two measures are different things and cannot be compared easily, one might expect that they see the same candidate as winning, regardless of how much.

Yes, you're right.  I've added a little note to address this.

Why do you exclusively consider the betting market as biased? We see polls with similar descrepancy depdening on the outlets' political orientation. It's the betting market with huge amounts of money at stake, existentially relying on highly accurate polls; you did not consider this.

I don't. I was summarizing the other answers that I thought missed the point.  I've rephrased to try to make it clear that I'm not offering an opinion on the bias or lack of bias in betting markets or polls.

(+1) That's a very important point. That said, ohwilleke touched on this already and the fact remain that polls-based forecast like the 538 forecast (not polling averages) seem closer to 50-50 than the betting markets.

+1 for pointing the difference between the difference on the amount of votes between candidates and the probability that that difference goes on a given direction.

Polls measure the declared vote intentions of polled people. And they are pretty good at that — the probability that a poll's sample differs from the general population is small. However, that does not accurately represent actual election outcomes, because each of the four words I highlighted in bold can induce a difference.
Note that these differences have nothing to do with a poll's error margin. The error margin is about the difference between asking a random sample and asking everyone. It's irrelevant to differences that are either about a biased sample, or due to not measuring exactly the same thing.
Betting markers think that there are significant differences. What could the differences be?
Polled
Polls measure the intentions of people who reply to polls. There is an inherent bias there: some people are harder to reach, and some people don't like answering polls. This was made very apparent in the US in the 1948 presidential election, when a major newspaper reported “Dewey defeats Truman” before all the votes were counted — and Truman ended up winning. This headline was partly pushed by eager supporters of Dewey, but it was also influenced by polls that gave Dewey as the winner.
Pollsters subsequently examined their methods and realized that their sample were biased. One factor was that most polls were conducted over the telephone. But poor people didn't have telephones, and poor people were more likely to vote for Truman. Pollsters were aware of that and tried to compensate, but after the 1948 shake-up, they found that they hadn't compensated enough.
Finding representative samples is difficult. Pollsters try to apply quotas of certain age groups, genders, education levels, economic status, etc. But they can't account for all possible biases in the sample.
Intentions
People can change their minds. People who are undecided, and say so to pollsters, might be more likely to vote for one candidate or the other.
Pollsters can try to adjust their predictions by modelling undecided people. They can follow people throughout an election cycle and count how many people reported voting for each candidate while having declared themselves as undecided before the election. That gives pollsters figures from previous elections. But it's hard to know to what extent this data from previous elections apply to the current election.
Conversely, people who declared that they would vote might end up not voting, or changing their mind and voting for a different candidate. Again, pollsters can try to measure election-day changes of mind from previous elections, but it's hard to know to what extent this will carry over to the current election.
Declared
People don't always report their vote accurately to pollsters. There are systematic biases that are relatively consistent in time and space.
In the US, one such bias is known as the Bradley effect: in the past few decades, polls have tended to underestimate votes for white candidates. A sizeable number of people refrain from telling pollsters that they'll vote for a certain candidate just because he's white.
In the United Kingdom, there is a bias known as the shy Tory factor (Tory = Conservative). People are less likely to tell pollsters that they'll vote for Conservative candidates. In France, there was for a long time a similar bias that the extreme right party (“Front National”, later renamed to “Rassemblement National”) was underestimated in polls. It was made especially apparent in the 2002 election when the extreme right candidate came second in the presidential election, with the main left-wing candidate placing third and thus not eligible for the second round. The underestimation of the extreme right in polls was known and pollsters tried to correct for it, but they underestimated the underestimation. In recent years, the “shy FN voter” effect has disappeared, a sign of the normalization of extreme right voting among a significant part of the French population.
Interestingly, polls in the modern United States tend to underestimate votes for women — the less well known Richards effect. This may be compounded in a campaign where women's rights play an important role and where women in some places may be afraid of revealing that they won't vote for the anti-women candidate. This is somewhat less studied and it's hard to know how impactful it will be.
Vote
Polls attempt to find out who people will vote for. It's actually very likely that more people will vote for Harris than for Trump, just like more people voted for Gore than Bush in 2000 and for Clinton than Trump in 2016. But that's not how the US presidential elections work: it's about who gets the majority in each electoral district (48 states, DC, and the multiple districts in two states). The arrangement of the districts overrepresent certain states that have a Republican majority.
A second factor is that there is a risk that some votes may be prevented, and the votes may not be counted accurately. The US have a considerable history of disenfranchisement, and Republicans are actively trying to suppress unfavorable votes in the 2024 election. Ahead of the election, they have been purging voter rolls in unfavorable demographics, made it harder for college students to vote](https://19thnews.org/2024/10/college-students-barriers-voting-registration-challenges/) in some states, are trying to block some overseas ballots, limited access to polling places... In 2020, Trump called to stop counting votes, knowing that early results are strongly biased towards rural areas and in-person votes, both of which are biased towards Republicans. In 2024, in some states, such as Georgia, the Republican-controlled administration has been trying to set rules that would cause votes from Democrat-leaning demographics not to be counted. Will these attempts succeed and to what extent? Pollsters aren't trying to answer that, but betters are.

The two numbers are not the same thing (see K. A. Buhr's answer), so you should not expect them to be the same.
I think it's also worth mentioning that:

Many of the states in the US election simply don't matter. That's why there is a concept of a "battleground state". There are seven of these. When evaluating which candidate is likely to win, you need to evaluate how likely each candidate is to win a particular battleground state, and then how many of those states he/she needs to win in order to win the election. You are looking at questions like "What if Trump wins Arizona, Georgia, and Michigan, while Harris wins Nevada, North Carolina, Pennsylvania and Wisconsin? Does that mean Trump wins the election, or Harris does?". The polls you're looking at don't generally do this. It's entirely possible that Harris polls better nationally, yet be firmly behind in odds of winning.
The other thing is that the polls weren't exactly reliable in 2016 and 2020. This doesn't mean that they won't be reliable this year, of course, but a bettor could reasonably (?) think that it will happen again.

Ultimately, it's gambling, and gambling is not always based on reason (or lottery operators would go bust).

If you look at 2016 then both mentioned methods (election polling and electing result betting) got the tendency (who will win the US presidency) wrong. In 2020 however, both (polling and betting) got the tendency right. So both methods have errors, which is not a surprise actually.
And because the errors likely are not completely identical, it's also not a surprise if they go in different directions like they might do now. That is just because of inherent uncertainty about the future and nobody being able to predict the US presidency always correctly. Sometimes these predictions will simply disagree. It's especially expected for a very close race like the current one. The closer the race is, there higher the error probability for the prediction of who will win. (Of course they could also both agree and both be wrong like in 2016.)
What the polls and the bets (who are wildly fluctuating) want to tell us is mostly that both candidates have a similar chance of winning. Or in other words, this US election voting or voter turnout (in the battleground states) can make the difference for the US presidency.
Also the average of the polls isn't really in favor of Harris (in the battleground states) or only very slightly, but there are also polls that favor Trump. It's simply undecidable for now.
Finally, betting can also just be seen as a poll weighted by money that is staked in the bet. People having invested money that they want to keep (probably, although they are betting so maybe not so strongly) may be incentivized more to estimate the chances for US presidency more unbiased but then the sample size might be lower for betting and the statistical normalization that is often done for polls is missing. And for polling money may be involved too, polling companies sometimes pay people for filling out questionnaires.
